# Sort 'pandas.core.series.Series' so that largest value is in the centre

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
x = pd.Series([3, 1, 1]) 
print(x)

0    3
1    1
2    1
```

I would like to sort the output so that the largest value is in the center. Like this:

```
0    1
1    3
2    1
```

Do you have any ideas on how to do this also for series of different lengths (all of them are sorted with decreasing values). The length of the series will always be odd.

Thank you very much!

Anna

Comment: What is expected output from `x = pd.Series(range(6))` ?

Comment: The expected output would be: 0 2 4 6 5 3 1
However it is expected that the numbesr mirror each other. So,  I have twice the number 2, twice the number 3 and so on. 
In the upper example it was 3, 1, 1. (expected output: 1,3,1)
t could also be 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1 (expected output: 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 1)

Comment: The length will always be odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort values and then use indexing with join values by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
x = pd.Series([6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1])

x = x.sort_values()
print (pd.concat([x[::2], x[len(x)-2:0:-2]]))
5    1
3    2
1    4
0    6
2    4
4    2
6    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
x = pd.Series(range(7))

x = x.sort_values()
print (pd.concat([x[::2], x[len(x)-2:0:-2]]))
0    0
2    2
4    4
6    6
5    5
3    3
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: it's not necesary sort because these are already sorted.